# New products are not in catalog

Tags: magento2

I create products in Magento 2 with visibility in catalog and search, but I can search the product but not in catalog. The cron is executed many times correctly since the creation but not solve the problem. If I executed `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` solve the problem but I want this is executed alone

Comment: you have to check from backend, product visibility set to Catalog,Search and reindex.

Answer (score 0):

Check stock quantity of the product - it needs to be greater than 0.
Product status field should be set to "Enabled".
Visibility should be "Catalog" (for product to be shown) or "Catalog, Search".
Categories field should not be left empty.
Make changes and save product then run php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: Thanks for the response. The stock is greather than 0, and product show when search the sku, but not show when you search in menu in the category of product

Comment: I can't understand what you mean "but not show when you search in menu in the category of product"

Comment: I put an example. If sku is 123 and I search 123 Magento show the product but If the product is in category Category1 and I click in Category1 Magento not show the product

Comment: Go to admin and check is the Admin->Products->Categories - go to Products in Category and check is the product in that category

Comment: Yes, is in the category, I think the problem is that something not work in cron but in cron log show all correctly

Comment: Can you execute the reindex command manually, log in to your server thru ssh, go to magento root dir and run php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: I run this and work but if I create more products I have to reindex manually too. I want this automatic

Comment: It looks like that you cronjob is not set correctly or is not working, check it why is not  working.